# Masking the numbers and characters in python

Tags: python-3.x

How to mask the digits without affecting the characters and hyphens in the data.
i tried this basic code

```
def maskif(cc):
    if len(cc) <= 6:
        return cc
    if cc==[]:
        return []
    if len(cc) >6:
#         dd=cc.replace('-','')
        if cc.isdigit():
            print (cc[:1] + '#' * (len(cc)-5) + cc[-4:])
        elif not cc.isdigit():
            dd=cc.replace('-','')
            print (dd[:1] + '#' * (len(dd)-5) + dd[-4:])
            print(dd)

        else: 
            print('int')   


    else:
        print('valid')
```

My input and outputs should be:

```
A234-2345-3456-ABCD ----- A###-####-####-ABCD
ABCD-EFGH-IJKLM-NOPQ ------  ABCD-EFGH-IJKLM-NOPQ
4556-3646-0793-5616 ----- 4###-####-####-5616
A1234567BCDEFG89HI------A#######BCDEFG89HI
```

Comment: It looks like your actual requirements are more complex.  Could you be more specific?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `re.sub` for finding and substituting the digits:

```
data = ['A234-2345-3456-ABCD',
'ABCD-EFGH-IJKLM-NOPQ',
'4556-3646-0793-5616',
'A1234567BCDEFG89HI']

import re

def mask(cc):
    return cc[:1] + re.sub(r'\d', r'#', cc[1:-4]) + cc[-4:]

for d in data:
    print(mask(d))
```

Prints:

```
A###-####-####-ABCD
ABCD-EFGH-IJKLM-NOPQ
4###-####-####-5616
A#######BCDEFG89HI
```